# Как вернуть стили на админ-панель в Django

Tags: python, django

Поставил свой проект на хостинг pythonanywhere. И вроде бы все корректно работает, но пропали стили в админ панели. Искал ответ на вопрос в интернете, но нашел только ответы по типу изменить настройки в ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX, который давно не поддерживается. При попытке использовать collectstatic вылезает ошибка

```
ImproperlyConfigured("You're using the staticfiles app "
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: You're using the staticfiles app without having set the STATIC_ROOT setting to a filesystem path.
```

Как вернуть стили админки в 2021 году на Django 3.2 ?

Comment: в `setting.py` что прописано в переменной `STATIC_ROOT`? По пути, которая содержит эта переменная собирается вся статика проекта, в т.ч. и для админки. Далее вся статика может браться из данной директории без лишних действий с вашей стороны

Comment: @Дмитрий, такой переменной у меня нет, добавлял статику через ~STATIC_URL~

Comment: Можно добвить, вызвать `collectstatic`, и все должно заработать.

Comment: @Дмитрий, в вопросе я указал, что при вызове collectstatic возникает ошибка

Comment: 1. Добавить `STATIC_ROOT = <path>`, 2. Вызвать `collectstatic` 3. Все! У вас вылетает ошибка по причине, того что `Django` не знает куда ложить все это дело. [Документация](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/staticfiles/). Другой вариант воспользоваться `findstatic` и указать напрямую найденную статику для админки

Comment: @Дмитрий, большое спасибо. Всё получилось

Comment: на здоровье) всегда пожалуйста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавить STATIC_ROOT =  в файл settings.py, 2. Вызвать py manage.py collectstatic 3. Все!